# Как отключить интернет на windows с помощью кода на java?

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, lan, ethernet

Я просто нажимаю на кнопку и интернет отключается, нажимаю снова и он включается. Такое возможно сделать. И так что бы он работал на разных компьютера с разными Windows.

Мне написали что нужно отредактировать этот вопрос, так как вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта. Но я не понимаю зачем, я же не прошу людей сделать курсовую за меня. Мне стало не понятно как написать код, и я задал вопрос. Внизу даже ответил один, просто это не помогло.

Comment: что попытались сделать вы и что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Нет. понятия не имею как это сделать. просто нужно для курсовой работы.

Answer (score 3):

Вставьте строчку кода:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netsh wlan disconnect");
```

Comment: Вроде не работает.

Comment: у меня работает) сам проверил

Comment: Попробуйте создать отдельный проект и в main запустить эту строку

Comment: wlan это ведь Wi-Fi?

Comment: не уверен, но скорее всего это так

Comment: Даже в main не работает